# Java - I can't replace char 'Á' with another char in String

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, char

Why this "Á" alphabet doesn't change? this code works on the other alphabet but Á.

```
public class Convert {
    static String turkishCharacterConverter(String s) {
        StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
        char[] charArr = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
            if (charArr[i] == '˝') {
                x.append('I');
            } else if (charArr[i] == '˛') {
                x.append("S");
            } else if (charArr[i] == '') {
                x.append("G");
            } else if (charArr[i] == 'ˆ') {
                x.append("O");
            } else if (charArr[i] == '¸') {
                x.append("U");
            } else if (charArr[i] == 'Á') {
                x.append("C");
            } else {
                x.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return x.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(turkishCharacterConverter("˝˛˝˝nda"));
        System.out.println(turkishCharacterConverter("ˆlÁt¸¸m"));
    }
}
```

and java print

ISIGInda

OlÁtUGUm ( i want to make java print "OlCtUGUm" )

Comment: Try to safe your file in UTF-8. Which editor are you using?

Comment: somebody solved it, the problem is in char[] charArr = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray(); I'm comparing Á with á :) thanks anyway @CedricReichenbach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of `char[] charArr = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();`

You are comparing `Á` with its lower case `á`. The other characters are already in lower case so it works fine for them.

Comment: @Arief27 Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

It is making `Á as á` because of using lowercase. try using this

```
if(charArr[i] == 'á')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
'\u00c1'
```

instead of 'Á'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because [unicode contains duplicated characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_characters_in_Unicode).